Asymptotic Theory in Cross-Sectional Dependence
I've recently started studying cross-sectional dependence in panels from Pesaran's (2015) book, and I’d appreciate your help in developing an intuitive understanding of the concepts. Here’s a summary of the key definitions and assumptions:
Consider the double-index process $\{z_{it}, i \in \mathbb{N}, t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$,and let the random vector at time $t$ defined as $\mathbf{z}_t = (z_{1t}, z_{2t}, \dots, z_{Nt})^\prime$.
The author assumes:
i) The process, $z_t$, has  mean $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{z}_t) = \mathbf{0}$, and covariance matrix $ \mathrm{Var}(\mathbf{z}_t) = \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_t,$
where $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_t$ is an $N \times N$ symmetric, nonnegative definite matrix.
ii) The diagonal elements of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_t$ (variances) are bounded: $0 < \sigma_{ii,t} \leq K, \quad \forall i = 1, 2, \dots, N$
where $K$ is a finite constant independent of $N$.
Then, the author says that summary measures of cross-sectional dependence based on $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_t$ can be constructed in a number of different ways.
Then, let  $\mathbf{w}_t = (w_{1t}, w_{2t}, \dots, w_{Nt})^\prime$, for $t \in T \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$, be a vector of non-stochastic weights.
A possible measure of cross-sectional dependence can be based on the behavior of weighted cross-sectional averages:
\begin{equation}
\bar{z}_{\mathbf{w}t} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_{it} z_{it} = \mathbf{w}_t^\prime \mathbf{z}_t
\end{equation}
at a point in time $t$, for $t \in T$, where $\mathbf{z}_t$ satisfies Assumption 1, and the sequence of weight vectors $\mathbf{w}_t$,  satisfies the following Granularity condition that can be summarized by iii) and iv):
iii)
\begin{equation}
 \| \mathbf{w}_t \| = \sqrt{\mathbf{w}_t^\prime \mathbf{w}_t} = O(N^{-1/2}),
 \end{equation}
where $\| \mathbf{w}_t \|$ is the Euclidean norm of the weight vector.
iv)
\begin{equation}
 \frac{w_{jt}}{\| \mathbf{w}_t \|} = O(N^{-1/2}), \quad \text{uniformly for all } j = 1, \dots, N.
\end{equation}
Eventually, Weak Cross-Sectional Dependence (CWD) and Strong Cross-Sectional Dependence (CSD) are defined as:
The process $\{\mathbf{z}_t\}$ is said to be weakly cross-sectionally dependent at a given point in time $t \in T$, if for any sequence of weight vectors $\{\mathbf{w}_t\}$ satisfying the granularity conditions (iii)–(iv) we have:
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathrm{Var}(\mathbf{w}_t^\prime \mathbf{z}_t) = 0. 
\end{equation}
and
the process $\{\mathbf{z}_t\}$ is said to be cross-sectionally strongly dependent at a given point in time $t \in T$, if there exists a sequence of weight vectors $\{ w_t \}$ satisfying (iii)–(iv) and a positive constant $K$, independent of $N$, such that for any $N$ sufficiently large (and as $N \to \infty\ $):
\begin{equation}
 \mathrm{Var}(\mathbf{w}_t^\prime \mathbf{z}_t) \geq K > 0, \quad \text{for sufficiently large } N. \label{CSD}
\end{equation}
Questions:
Q1: My understanding of iii) and iv):
Condition (iii), says that the Euclidean norm of the weight vector grows no faster than $N^{-1/2}$ as $N$ approaches infinity. Intuitively, as the number of units ($N$) increases, the norm of the weight vector decreases at a rate of the square root of $N$. Mathematically, there exist positive constants $C$ and $N_0$ such that $ \| \mathbf{w}_t \| \leq C \cdot N^{-1/2}$, for all $N \geq N_0$.
Condition (iv) says that the ratio of individual weights to the norm of the weight vector grows no faster than $N^{-1/2}$. It ensures that no single weight becomes disproportionately large as $N$ increases.
Is that correct?
Q2: Interpretation of Weak and strong cross sectional dependence:
Weak Dependence:
As $N \to \infty$, the variance of the weighted average $\mathbf{w}_t^\prime \mathbf{z}_t$ shrinks to $0$. This suggests weak correlations between the units $\{z_{it}\}$ and the aggregation dampens any collective effect.
Strong Dependence:
Even as $N \to \infty$, the variance of $\mathbf{w}_t^\prime \mathbf{z}_t$ remains bounded below by a constant $K > 0$.
This indicates strong correlations, often due to shared common factors or mutual dependencies. In this case aggregation does not "average out" the dependence.
Is that correct?
Q3: What do these weights ($w_{it}$) are in practice?
